# Tag specific page not working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

Page returning the question associated with a tag like

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft

Are not working currently.

Comment: I'm getting this also. Example: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360 0 questions

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this. I think you're on the wrong tab..

Comment: My bad was on the HOT tab and there is no Hot question tagged with this, sorry.

Comment: Still, [the hot page for `roguelike`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=roguelike&sort=hot&pagesize=15) says there are 0 questions tagged; the [newest page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=roguelike&sort=newest&pagesize=15) begs to differ and says one; the [question page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/430) disagrees and says there are two. I guess this isn't completely right? Could it be that [this other question tagged `roguelikes`](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146) is mixing up the counts?

Comment: If I go to the tags page, and then click on one of the tags which is supposed to have questions assoicated with it (i.e. xbox 360), I usually get 0 questions on the tagged questions.

Comment: "Me too!" Tag pages are missing questions that I know are there.

Comment: It seems that when you click a tag it defaults to the hot tab instead of the newest like it does in SO